# Split existing column to multiple new columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

[image: original data frame]

I would like this result:

[image: expected result]

I wrote this code:

```
test$statetwentyeighteen = test$state[test$year=="2018"]
```

but I get this wrong result:

[image: wrong result]

Can you please help see how to revise the code?

---

**update:**

I am having a new issue with this matter. when the original table is updated to this:
[image: updated data frame]

this code no longer works

```
test %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(state_twentyeighteen = state[year == 2018])
```

instead I get this error message:

```
Error: Column `state_twentyeighteen` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 2
```

Can you please see what revision should be done to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(state_twentyeighteen = state[year == 2018])
```

and similarly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, state_twentyeighteen := state[year == 2018], name]
```